# Java 2Dimensional Arrays Odd pattern numbers

Tags: arrays, 2d

[Code base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpkJN.png)

How do I constuct a 2D code to match the pattern given?

Answer (score 0):

For example this way:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class arrays {
     public static void main(String []args){
         
         int dim_x = 4;
         int dim_y = 4;
         
         int[][] code = new int[dim_y][dim_x * 2];
         int value = 7;
         
         for (int fy = 0; fy < dim_y; fy++) {
             for (int fx = 0; fx < dim_x; fx++) {
                 code[fy][fx * 2] = value++;
                 code[fy][fx * 2 + 1] = value++;
                 
                 value += 2;
             }
         }
         
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(code));
     }
}
```